# How to avoid rerunning a subquery used multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

The following is a simplified example of a problem I'm running into. Assume I have a query "SomeQuery" (SELECT... FROM... WHERE...) that gives an output that looks like this:

| Status | MyDate |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6/14/2021 |
| A | 6/12/2021 |
| B | 6/10/2021 |
| A | 6/8/2021 |
| B | 6/6/2021 |
| A | 6/4/2021 |

I need to get the earliest status A date that is greater than the maximum status B date. In this case 6/12/2021.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(MyDate) AS DateNeeded
FROM
  SomeQuery
WHERE
  Status = 'A'
  AND MyDate > (
    SELECT
      MAX(MyDate) AS MaxDateB
    FROM
      SomeQuery
    WHERE
      Status = 'B'
  )
```

This works, but I would like to avoid running the subquery twice. I tried assigning an alias to the first instance of the subquery, and then using that alias in place of the second instance, but this results in an "Invalid object name" error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to provide an answer without an actual [mre] but most likely you can use a window function.

Comment: I would use a CTE.  You might be able to join the table back to itself joining on date and different types.

Comment: @drHodge Self-join likely to be slow, and is effectively the same thing as the subquery. Window function is almost certainly the best answer

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and provide the desired results

Comment: Hi @JohnCappelletti, as I mentioned the result should be 6/12/2021, which is the earliest A date after all the B dates.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I realized now how my post could be misleading. When I said "after every status B date", I meant that I just wanted a single date that was greater than the maximum status B date. I'll edit the post for that. Thanks.

Comment: Considering that you're really looking at 2 reads (one where Status = A and one where Status = B) then just about any plan will require reading twice (even CTEs). A window function may only do 1 set of reads but will add time for computation. Another approach is to first store the results of `SomeQuery` in a #temporary table with a non-clustered index on `Status, MyDate` so it will be sorted in a way that helps. With the index, the number of reads will be minimal and practically instantaneous; however you will need to spend the extra time in creating the temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but to avoid hitting table twice you could use window function:

```
select top(1) Mydate from 
(
 select *, max(case when Status = 'B' then Mydate end) over () MaxBDate from data 
) t 
where status = 'A'
and MyDate > MaxBDate
order by Mydate
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1872545cf2055eac719a3a8c358a97f6)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after exactly, but it is possible to do something like this:

```
;WITH cte (MaxMyDate) as
(
   SELECT
      MAX(MyDate) AS MaxDateB
    FROM
      SomeQuery
    WHERE
      Status = 'B'    
)
SELECT
  MIN(MyDate) AS DateNeeded
FROM
  SomeQuery
WHERE
  Status = 'A'
  AND MyDate > (SELECT MaxMyDate from cte)
```

Some may find this a bit easier to read, since some of the complexity is moved to a cte.

Comment: Hi Moe, thanks for your answer, but this doesn't quite fix the issue I was having. "SomeQuery" is a select statement that's several lines long, so I was trying to avoid having it in more than one place. I wasn't aware of CTEs before today however, and I found that if I use my original solution but have "SomeQuery" defined as a CTE, I can then use that instead of listing out the query twice, so your answer was still useful. Thanks.

Comment: @StevenLightning - if "SomeQuery" is complicated, what you could do, is create a user defined function (UDF), and define your query in there. Then you can reuse it from multiple places. But note there are different types of UDFs - some of them can have performance issues. In your case, you want an inline table valued UDF.